# How to autofill cells in Excel based on info in another cell

Tags: excel

I'm trying to change some things at our Excel register at work. I have 2 cells with a drop down menu. I want one of them to select an option automatically when I choose an option from the dropdown in the other one.

For example:
First dropdown menu is name of office - I select office in UK.
The other dropdown menu is with different addresses. I want it to automatically select the address of the UK office when I select UK on the first dropdown.

I have access to the nomenclatures for each dropdown menu. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim arr As Variant, element As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            str = .Range("A" & i).Value

            arr = Split(.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1, ",")

            For y = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

                If InStr(1, arr(y), str) > 0 Then
                    .Range("B" & i) = arr(y)
                    Exit For
                Else
                    .Range("B" & i).ClearContents
                End If

            Next y

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```